# Vision api not detecting QR code on some devices

Tags: android, google-play-services, qr-code, vision-api

I am using Vision api for detecting QR codes. It works well on a samsung device but not on LG device. Both devices are running on version 6.0.1 and there's no error as well. Any advice?

Comment: Did you try calling [`isOperational()`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/vision/Detector.html#isOperational()) on your barcode detector?

Comment: Yes I am using it and displaying toast if its not operational but still no luck

Comment: Did you also try [`detectorIsOperational()`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/vision/Detector.Detections#detectorIsOperational())?

Comment: Not yet. Gonna try it

Comment: While you're at it, try restarting your phone. Someone reported an issue that `isOperational()` returns `false` for some reason, but once the phone is restarted, it returns `true`.

Comment: Thanks. Let me see

Comment: @GergelyKőrössy still no luck :(

Comment: if my answer working for you please accept answer :)

Answer (score 1):

Here some sample of **Zxing-Library** and **Vision API** hope it will help you.

The sample projects base on **Zxing-Library**

[**Zxing Code Sample1**](https://github.com/shubhamnishad97/ScanBarcode-QRcode) or

[**Zxing Code Sample2**](https://github.com/pintukumarpatil/ZxingBarcodeAndQrcodeScannerBox)

While **Vision API** for QR Bar Code try this

[**Vision API Code Sample1**](https://github.com/DevExchanges/BarcodeScannerVisonAPI) or 
[image]

[**Vision API Code Sample2**](https://github.com/KingsMentor/MobileVisionBarcodeScanner) or

[**Vision API Code Sample3**](https://www.androidhive.info/2017/08/android-barcode-scanner-using-google-mobile-vision-building-movie-tickets-app/)

Comment: The Mobile Vision API is indeed for [Barcode detection](https://developers.google.com/vision/android/barcodes-overview) as well.

Comment: I have used zxing library but it's not detecting barcodes properly

Comment: Vision Api is used for qrcode and barcode scanning.

Comment: Okay but i prefer to use vision api for recognition and zxing for qr or bar 
here [here i use both and working fine](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.fsapps.imagetotext.textrecognizer)

Comment: It's okay if _you_ use those libs for barcode detection, but don't state in your answer that the Vision API is unable to do so because you're just simply wrong.

Comment: @Attaullah I am following the same tutorial but its not detecting qr codes on some devices

Answer (score 0):

I faced this same issue that QR not detected on Redmi and Infinix devices, here is my solution:

**Zxing Library Version**

```
implementation 'com.google.zxing:core:3.4.0'
```

Just pass your Bitmap in this function and this will return the string value:

```
public static String getQRDataFromBitmap(Bitmap bitmap) {
    ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, stream);
    int[] intArray = new int[bitmap.getWidth() * bitmap.getHeight()];
    bitmap.getPixels(intArray, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), 0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight());
    LuminanceSource source = new RGBLuminanceSource(bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(), intArray);
    Reader reader = new MultiFormatReader();
    try {
        Result result = reader.decode(new BinaryBitmap(new HybridBinarizer(source)));
        return result.getText();
    } catch (NotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    } catch (ChecksumException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    } catch (FormatException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}
```